# F2PY: gfortran compiler not found and missing DLLs

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I need to use a Fortran77 script from Python, so I'm trying to use the F2PY package. I have no Fortran knowledge, and didn't have any Fortran compiler on my Windows 10, so I installed gfortran following [this guide](https://masuday.github.io/fortran_tutorial/install_gfortran_windows.html). I think the installation worked, because if I run the `gfortran` command from MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit I get

```
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Then I attempted to run the example from the F2PY documentation at [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/f2py.getting-started.html#the-quick-way), but I get this error:

```
error: extension 'fib1' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

I guess F2PY doesn't see the gfortran compiler, so I set an environment variable following Step Four of [this guide](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/F2PY_Windows.html): I have created a new environment variable (a user variable, not a system one) called `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and set it to `C:\msys64\usr\bin\gfortran\include`. If I try re-running the example, I get the same error.

What am I missing? Should I use a system variable instead of a user variable? Also, the value of the variable looks a bit odd, because the only instance of `gfortran` I found on my computer is a file, not a directory...
Thanks in advance!

---

Update: I was able to solve this issue by adding `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to my Path!
Now I can successfully compile the Fortran module, but when I try to import the extension module in Python I get

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing fib1: Couldn't find the specified module.
```

I also included `C:\msys64\usr\lib` in my Path, but the error persists. Any ideas?

---

New update: I was finally able to solve the missing DLL error! For me, when I run the command to create the extension module (`python -m numpy.f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1`), two things are created in my current directory: a `fib1.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` file, which I think is the extension module itself, and a `fib1` directory, containing a `.libs` directory. This last directory contains the following file:

```
libfib1.OPD3BD7YADI2T777PBURWLTYIK5TRWK2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
```

I just copied this file from the `.libs` directory to the current directory (the same where I have the .pyd file), and now the exension module runs fine!

I hope this can help :)

Comment: Did you import `numpy` first?

Comment: Yes, I did; anyway PyCharm signals that importing numpy is unnecessary if I just try to print the extension module documentation, as i'm doing now...

Comment: Hm, OK. I tested the example, and it worked right a way, on linux though. Try running from the terminal, not PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but the result is the same.